# How to change/add column background colors in Lyx? I can easily change/add colors of rows, but not columns

Tags: tables, lyx, color, columns

Bear with me, this isn't a duplicate question. I can successfully change the row color in tables using the instructions here: http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables

(A similar question exists here: [Background for table cells in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15145/background-for-table-cells-in-lyx))

But when I add the command \columncolor{cyan}, it throws up some errors. The working example provided on the website has one of the columns colored in green, but I have no idea how they did it, since the command isn't present in the main editor (but it shows up in the source!).

Keep in mind I want to do this using *LyX* and don't want LaTeX code (which is already out there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to put the `\usepackage{colortbl}` package in your preamble. Then put the curser in the column where you want to change the background color. Then right click and go to `more -> settings`

Now, under `LaTeX Argument:` you have to put the following

```
>{\columncolor{darkgreen}\centering}c
```

where the `darkgreen` can be changed to any valid LaTeX color and `c` can be changed to a table alignment. I.e. `l,r,c` etc.